# How can I get a link from <a href="#" onClick=?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/sinonimi_regionali/ using python3 and beautifulsoup. I've parsed first page and I need to go to the second page, to third and etc.
Moving to another page is made by button(image):

```
<div class="next">
    <a href="#" onClick="doSearch(1, 4, 37); return false;" title="Pagina successiva">
        <img src="/export/system/modules/it.banzai.treccani.portale3/resources/images/arrow-right.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Please tell me, how can I get the link to go to next page? Or how can I move between pages using python?

Comment: BeautifulSoup only parses the page that it sees if there is no link there it will not find. One as @Wayne Werner said selenium is a good approach to do what you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going to need a Javascript engine, rather than Beautiful Soup.

One good approach is using browser automation via [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). Unless you feel like guessing - because you'll have to know what the `doSearch` function is actually doing, and if they change the Javascript then your code will no longer do what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using BeautifulSoup is that it returns a static page to you if the link is not in the html you cannot get it using BeautifulSoup as it is simply a parser and does not run the page.

As mentioned in the other answers a good approach to use this is selenium, You could also try and find the `doSearch` JavaScript work out what it is doing a replicate it on your python end this does seem a little messy though. After looking at the doSearch function selenium seems like your best shot.